# ¿Cómo insertar en una tabla el id de otra tabla en php codeigniter?

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter

Doy un ejemplo:
Tengo `TABLA1` y `TABLA2`. La primera tabla tiene `id` (autoincremental), `nombre`, `apellido`, `usuario`, `contraseña`. La segunda tabla tiene `id` (integer), `dni`.

Yo quisiera que una vez que inserte datos en `TABLA1`, la `TABLA2` tenga en el campo ID el id de la `TABLA1`.
¿Cómo hago el insertar de `TABLA2`?

Me manejo mucho con el CI_model de Codeigniter, las funciones Add, insert, pero veo que automáticamente se genera un id, por más que le mande como id el id de la `TABLA1`.
¿Cómo evito eso, o cómo sería mi función insertar para `TABLA2`?

El problema lo tengo en el modelo. Lo demás sí sé cómo hacerlo. Por favor evitar hacer ejemplos con `INSERT INTO...`, porque en el controlador hago varias cargas. Utilizo Postgresql.

Comment: Has intentado hacer un query retornando el id generado con el insert y luego usar ese id para guardarlo, postgres tiene la clausula opcional **RETURNING** para devolver algún valor despues de hacer un query.

Answer (score 1):

Para el ejemplo, tu TABLA2 debería tener su propio ID y una Llave foránea con el ID de la tabla 1, algo como

```
Tabla1  | Tipo
---------------
ID      | PK
Datos   | cosas

Tabla1    | Tipo
---------------
ID        | PK
fk_tabla1 | FK
Datos     | cosas
```

Así es como generas la relación entre las 2 tablas, piensa en cada tabla como un 'ser único' que genera relación con otro 'ser único' a través de una llave foránea (FK). Esto lo hacemos suponiendo que la relación es 1:n

Una vez llegado a eso, primero realizas la inserción en la Tabla1, tomas el ID de la tabla 1 y la insertas en el fk_tabla1 de la Tabla2, es recomendable que tu campo de la tabla2 NO se llame ID ya que podría generar algún conflicto de nombres.

En caso de codeigniter, puedes saber el id

```
$this->db->insert_id()
```

saludos

Comment: hola, gracias por responderme, mi problema no es q no puedo obtener el ultimo id de la TABLA1, sino que quiero insertar el id de la tabla1 como id primario de la TABLA2, o sea una relacion 1:1, :)

Answer (score 0):

Creo entender lo que quieres hacer, si lo he entendido mal de antemano una disculpa.

Quieres crear un registro y obtener el id del registro que guardaste para usarlo en la segunda tabla.

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/helpers.html

usa insert_id

Comment: hola Sergio, gracias por responderme, mi problema no es q no puedo obtener el ultimo id de la TABLA1, sino que quiero insertar el id de la tabla1 como id primario de la TABLA2, o sea una relacion 1:1, :)

Comment: Te recomiendo que mejor uses otro campo dentro de la tabla que puedas comparar, de otra manera tendrías problema con el autonumérico.